# "in Hinblick auf" vs. "im Hinblick auf"

Tags: word-usage, phrase, article

Beides sei laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hinblick) zulässig und die Variante mit "im" sei gebräuchlicher. Alle, die "in Hinblick auf" als falsch ansehen sowie die, die behaupten, es gäbe keinen Unterschied (evtl. außer der Verwendungshäufigkeit), hören bitte auf zu lesen. Frage an den Rest: worin liegt der semantische und der stilistische Unterschied zwischen "in Hinblick auf" und "im Hinblick auf"?

Answer (score 3):

[Im Newsletterarchiv des Dudens](https://web.archive.org/web/20041001083224/http://www.duden.de/) ging es 2001 zwar nicht um *Hinblick,* sondern um *Urlaub,* aber möglicherweise lässt sich der kleine Unterschied zwischen *in* und *im* trotzdem semantisch und stilistisch übertragen:

> Kein Problem, ob Sie nun »in« oder »im« sagen, der Urlaub ist Ihnen auf jeden Fall sicher. Wenn auch »in Urlaub sein« eher für eine allgemeine Aussage steht (im Sinne von »nicht arbeiten«) und »im Urlaub sein« durch die Verschmelzung mit dem bestimmten Artikel »dem« eher einen konkreten (z. B. bereits erwähnten) Urlaub meint, so wird dieser feine Unterschied im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch kaum empfunden. Beide Varianten sind austauschbar. Genauso verhält es sich dann auch mit dem Erholungsgrad. Ob Sie nun im erholten (= in dem erholten) oder in erholtem (= sinngemäß: in einem erholten) Zustand sagen – der Effekt ist der gleiche, und grammatisch gesehen kann man auch nichts falsch machen. **Weitere Paradebeispiele für das freie grammatische Wahlrecht in diesem Bereich sind »in/im Hinblick auf«**, »in/im Bau sein« und »in/im Umlauf sein«.

Answer (score 2):

*In* Hinblick auf die tatsächliche Verwendung sehe ich keinen Unterschied.

*Im* Hinblick auf die unterschiedlichen Fälle könnte man einen semantischen Unterschied darin sehen, dass das Augenmerk entweder eher auf dem betrachteten Objekt oder eher auf dem Hinblicken selbst liegt.

Answer (score 0):

Einmal ist ein Artikel mit dabei (im Hinblick = in dem Hinblick), einmal nicht (in Hinblick). Das macht einen semantischen Unterschied, wie oben beschrieben.

Comment: Nein, *im* ist eine Präposition oder so ähnlich, meinetwegen auch *Determiner*, aber als Artikel gilt es üblicher Weise nicht. Falls du dennoch darauf bestehst, bedürfte es weiter Nachweise. "? In dem Hinblick auf" gibt es so jedenfalls nicht.